# R3 Corda: How is the validity of a transaction input checked with non-validating notaries without revealing the history of the transaction?

Tags: transactions, corda, consensus

I would like to include Corda in one of my projects to manage several assets between a large number of participants. In my use case, it is a critical requirement that the history of the assets is kept confidential.

The Corda documentation provides a good overview, but I still don't understand how consensus is reached with the non-validating notary without showing the history of the asset to the other party involved in the transaction.

Example:
Let's say Alice received $10 in transaction A from Charlie and now wants to give $20 to Bob in transaction B. The non-validating notary has recorded transaction A, but does not know that the value of the transaction was $10 (if I understood this correctly, https://docs.corda.net/key-concepts-notaries.html). Now Alice is using transaction A in transaction B and the notary can verify that it hasn't been used before. But what prevents Alice from telling Bob that she received $20 from Charlie in transaction A? Bob would have to look at the chain of transactions to verify that Alice can actually spend the $20. Therefore, Bob would know the history of the cash.

I would like to know if I misunderstood the documentation or if this is indeed an issue.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consensus in Corda happens at two levels:

- Validity Consensus
- Uniqueness Consensus

https://docs.corda.net/key-concepts-consensus.html

**Validity Consensus** involves running the contract by each of the parties involved in the transaction, and providing an agreement on the outcome of the transaction in the form for signature.

**Uniqueness Consensus**, on the other hand, is taken care of by the notary, where it checks for double-spending.

So in your example notary would just check if the input used in the transaction involving Alice paying $20 to Bob, the notary (non-validating) cannot check for the validity part of the consensus, all it checks is whether the input used in the transaction has already been spent or not.

The validity part i.e. where the $20 payment is actually valid, has to be checked at the contract level, by the parties. They need to check that the amount of cash in the input state should be equal to the amount of cash in the output state of the transaction.

This, however, would require Bob to verify the entire transaction chain, which is also the case with any transaction in Corda, this is required as Bob was unaware of the state in question as he never used to have to state to validate that it was indeed valid.

This could be a privacy breach, hence Charlie could use a confidential identity which transacting which would hide his identity in the transaction chain, hence Bob would only know that there was a transaction in which Alice received $10 from an anonymous entity and Charlie's identity would not be revealed.

In future versions of Corda, nodes would likely only exchange transaction chains in SGX-encrypted form. These transaction chains will then be verified inside an SGX enclave on the node. This will prevent nodes from seeing the contents of the transactions they are verifying (see the blogpost here: https://www.corda.net/2017/06/corda-sgx-privacy-update/). This may even go so far as to only allow nodes to see certain parts of the transactions they are signing.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Yes, this answers my question!

Comment: What would be your recommendation to hide Charlies identity in the current version? HD-wallets?

Comment: Use confidential identity: https://docs.corda.net/api-identity.html#confidential-identities

Comment: Thanks! Haven't seen that in the documentation.